# After writing to a stringstream, why does extracting into a string cause that string to become bogus?

Tags: c++, stl, operators, stringstream

I'm encountering a puzzling bug involving stringstream. I've got a object whose properties I want to dump to a file using dumpState(). This object has a number of member objects, each of which has had operator<< defined for them. Here's the code:

```
void dumpState(int step){
  stringstream s;
  s << DUMP_PATH << step;
  string filename;
  //s >> filename;

  fstream f;
  f.open("fuuuuu.csv", fstream::out); 
  //f.open(filename.c_str(), fstream::out);  

  f << numNodes << '\n';
  f << nodes << '\n';
  f << numEdges << '\n';
  f << edges << '\n';
  f.close();
}
```

My intention is of course to write to a file whose name is determined by step. Unfortunately, I find that the values outputted are bogus. Tracking the bug down, I found that if I comment out "s>>filename;" the values are correct.

There must be some sort of flushing problem going on, but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas on this rather evil looking bug?

UPDATE:

I think the problem was a rather complicated error due to a mistake elsewhere in my code. After restructuring my code, the original code I posted works fine.

Comment: it would have to be sstream since strstream.h is for strstream

Comment: @DougT. Indeed it is <sstream>

Comment: This is really interesting, it seems that this works when reading an integer out but a string fails.

Comment: I tried your code and it actually seems to work on ideone: http://ideone.com/flpox

Comment: @andyInCambridge - can you provide a complete, compilable sample program that demonstrates the problem? Also, what environment (OS, Compiler, &c) are you using?

Comment: What happens if you test for the stream's error state before your extract from it?

Comment: @wilhelmtell Aha! after s << DUMPATH << step; s.good() returns 1, and after s >> filename; s.good() returns 0! That must be an indication of something evil going on. Now to figure out what.

Comment: I'm using g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++0x foo.cpp . I wonder if it is the c++0x somehow?

Comment: Maybe -- can you post a compilable sample program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Rob, I think the problem was a rather complicated error due to a mistake elsewhere in my code. After restructuring my code, the original code I posted works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use an `ostringstream` and call `s.str()` to get the contents.

Comment: I'm curious though why his solution doesn't work, seems like it should.

Comment: @DougT. I avoid using stringstream in both directions.  I either use it to build strings or use it to parse a fixed string, but never both ways.

Comment: @Foo Bah, Could you elucidate your answer? I.e., as Doug asks, why doesn't my code work?

Comment: @DougT. in general, streams work in one direction (either writing or reading).  There is a single pointer for the location in the stream.  You would need a "read" head and a "write" head for the bidirectional stream to work.

Comment: @FooBah not true, there's seekp and tellp for the write position and seekg and tellg for the read position of the stream.

Comment: @FooBah, No. The exact same behavior occurs as in the original version. Intriguingly, the behavior occurs even if I comment fout the f << lines. I.e., merely declaring f, opening it, and closing it is enough to cause the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem using g++ 4.5.2 x86_64, so I can't confirm that this is the problem, but try this:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << DUMP_PATH << step;
s.flush();
std::string filename;
s >> filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other possible problems, `s >> filename;` will only read up to the first whitespace.

[Foo Bah has the correct solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614632/after-writing-to-a-stringstream-why-does-extracting-into-a-string-cause-that-str/7614730#7614730)